# Index lists for specific repeating element

Tags: python, list

How do I create a new list containing only the beginning index number of where the segment of True elements consecutively repeat?

> main_list = [True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, False]

The expected answer should be:

> true_index = [0,4]    #first repeating True starts at index 0 from main_list and the second repeating True starts at index 4 from main_list

If given a list like:

> l = [True,False,False]

Expected answer would be:

> index_list = [0]

**I need a simple code that does not require the use of numpy or groupby.**
I tried dividing the main_list into sublists first containing groups of the repeating True elements, however also struggled without using numpy or groupby.

Comment: If you show your efforts and where things went wrong, there are lots of people willing to help. But SO is not a work (home or other) offloading platform.

Comment: what if there is only one `True` say here: `lst = [True, False, False]` will the output be `[]` or `[0]`?

Comment: @Matiiss It would be [0] as it starts at index 0

Comment: @RebelHistone ok, but the issue is that `True` in this case does not repeat, there is only one so are the rules correct? also provide a [mre]

Comment: @Matiiss I understand but this is a simplified version of a much complex code that already dismisses that situation where there would only be a single True. All True elements in the list are repeated and I just require the methods on creating a list with the starting index number of each repeating segment.

Comment: @MarkoBorković This is a simplified version of a much complex code. I tried a different approach where I tried dividing the main_list into sublists first containing groups of the repeating True elements, however also struggled with that without using numpy or groupby.

Comment: @ShlomiF This is a simplified version of a much complex code where my previous work is not relevant to helping answering this part unfortunately. However, as I have mentioned, I tried dividing the main_list into sublists first containing groups of the repeating True elements, however also struggled with that without using numpy or groupby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a much shorter and solution, and might be preferable -

```
main_list = [True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, False]

def my_diff(my_list):
    return [1 if my_list[0] else 0] + [y - x for x, y in zip(my_list[:-1], my_list[1:])]

solution = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_diff(main_list)) if x == 1]

print(solution)
# [0, 4]
```

---

Explanation:
I'd personally solve this by using `np.diff`, and simply searching for the "transitions" (from `False` to `True`). But seeing as `numpy` is out of scope, I've just implemented a simple diff function, and the beginning of a sequence of `True`s is the same as having a difference of `1` between two consecutive elements.
And to make sure the first element isn't missed, if it's `True` then it's by definition the beginning of a sequence, and so we plant a `1` in place. Otherwise we don't :-).

To sum things up - look for "element - prev-element" being equal 1.

Comment: although it is shorter, that doesn't mean it is better, first of You shouldn't overuse list comprehensions (PEP 8 suggests not having more than 72 chars per line or sth like that) mainly because they are not that readable or at least they take time to understand and especially this applies to SO where there are a lot of people probably who don't understand them so You could also maybe try including the same solution but without using list comprehensions or at least explain the list comprehension so that people understand how it works

Comment: I didn't say it's better. But I added an explanation.

Comment: @ShlomiF Thank you for your explanation as it greatly helped understand what you did and why.

Comment: @Matiiss Yes, but as I mentioned there is a restriction given by which numpy and grouby cannot be used. So what ShlomiF did was perfect given that criteria to meet.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
main_list = [True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, False]

start_true = -1
last_added = -1
true_index = []

for i, value in enumerate(main_list):
    if value:
        if start_true == -1:
            start_true = i
        else:
            if start_true != last_added:
                true_index.append(start_true)
                last_added = start_true
    else:
        start_true = -1
        
print(true_index)
```

Also if you want the code to detect consecutive Trues including a single True here is a version that does that:

```
main_list = [True, False, False]

start_true = -1
last_added = -1
true_index = []

for i, value in enumerate(main_list):
    if value:
        if start_true == -1:
            start_true = i
        if start_true != last_added:
            true_index.append(start_true)
            last_added = start_true
    else:
        start_true = -1
        
print(true_index)
```