# Sum of repeated segments within main list

Tags: python, list

How do I create a new list containing the sum of all the True elements within the `main_list` where the True elements consecutively repeat?

```
main_list = [True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, False]
```

The expected answer is:

```
true_sum = [2,5]
#first repeating True segment starts at index 0 and contains 2 elements from main_list and the second repeating segment starts at index 4 from main_list and contains 5 True elements.
```

**I need a simple code that does not require the use of numpy or groupby.**

I tried dividing the main_list into sublists first containing groups of the repeating True elements, however also struggled without using numpy or groupby.

This is what I have tried but does not work for me:

```
true_sum = [sum(1 for i in main_list if i==True)]
```

Comment: Have you tried to iterate over the list with `enumerate`? That way, you can deal with the indices as well.

Comment: ```from collections import Counter```?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find same values in a list and group together a new list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30293071/how-can-i-find-same-values-in-a-list-and-group-together-a-new-list)

Comment: ok, there is a question on this site that is the exact same, except that one didn't include any attempts (since You tried something here is the link (it also contains answers)): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68339239/index-lists-for-specific-repeating-element/68339477?noredirect=1#comment120779189_68339477 or at least it is similar (way too similar)

Comment: @Sujay Unfortunately no as I require the sum of each repeating True segment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you want.  The final check, after the end of the loop, is needed to correctly handle the case where `main_list` ends in `True`:

```
def find_true_sum(main_list):
    count = 0
    true_sum = []
    for v in main_list:
        if v:
            count += 1
        elif count:
            true_sum.append(count)
            count = 0

    if count:
        true_sum.append(count)

    return true_sum
```

Here it is with your sample input:

```
main_list = [True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, False]
true_sum = find_true_sum(main_list)
```

This sets `true_sum` to:

```
[2, 5]
```

Additional example:

```
>>> find_true_sum([True, False, True, True, False, True, True])
[1, 2, 2]
>>>
```

This example requires the post-loop check of `count` to produce the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
main_list = [True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, False]
new_list = []
l_1=[]
num=0
for name in main_list:
    if name:
       num+=1
    elif num:
       new_list.append(num)
       num=0
print(new_list) #===== Prints [2, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```py
main_list = [True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, False]

x = [len(v) for v in "".join(str(int(i)) for i in main_list).split("0") if v]
print(x)
```

Prints:

```py
[2, 5]
```